# Pope anti-christ Protestant belief?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, papacy, antichrist

> There is no other Head of the Church but the Lord Jesus Christ (Eph
> 1:22; Col 1:18): nor can the Pope of Rome, in any sense be head
> thereof; but is that Antichrist, that man of sin and son of perdition,
> that exalteth himself in the Church against Christ, and all that is
> called God (Mat 23:8-10; 2 Thes 2:3-4, 8-9; Rev 13:6).
>
> WCF 25:6

> [Antichrist] shall be a master of sin and all iniquity, and yet will
> retain the name and appearance of Christ and call himself “most holy
> one; vicar of God; head of the Church,” and persecute all who will not
> obey him… the pope more than fits this description. — [Martin
> Luther](https://purelypresbyterian.com/2017/02/22/the-pope-is-antichrist/)

Do still protestants believe that the pope is the antichrist?

Comment: Some do, some don't. Anyone in particular you were wanting to know the answer of?

Comment: This needs to be scoped due to the wide diversity of opinion within that which refers to itself as 'Christian'.

Comment: @curiousdannii, not a specific one. but in mainline protestant denominations like Lutherans, Calvinists, Anglicans, etc...

Comment: September 2022 Question: How central is the claim the pope is the antichrist to Protestant theology?  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92752/how-central-is-the-claim-the-pope-is-the-antichrist-to-protestant-theology

Comment: Some denominations may still claim that the Pope was/is the Antichrist but things have moved on since then.  For example, one denomination says the harlot of Revelation, Babylon the Great, is all false religion.  They also say that all Trinitarian churches are part of the Antichrist, thereby embracing most Protestant denominations as well as Catholicism. I think you need to drop the catholicism tag because you are not asking if Catholics think the pope is the antichrist.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, I am a Protestant who does NOT believe the Pope is the Antichrist.  Did you read the question and answers in the link I provided?